# Vertical Menu with submenus flying out when mouse is hovered

Tags: html, css, submenu

I am trying to create a vertical menu with fly outs .That is a vertical menu with sub-menus.What is wrong with the following code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #navmenu ul ul li a {
                border:1px solid #888888; border-bottom: none; font-size:12pt; line-height: 1.6em; color:#303030; background-color:#a5a5a5; background-image:none;
            }
            #navmenu {
                width: 150px; /* set width of menu */
            }  
            #navmenu ul {
                list-style-type:none; margin:0px;   padding:0px;
            }
            #navmenu a {
                text-decoration:none; border: 1px solid #303030; width:170px;   display:block;   text-align:center;   font-size:14pt;   line-height:2em; background:url(Button_top.gif) repeat-x left;   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:white;
            }
            #navmenu a:hover {
                color: #a00;
                /* red text color on hover */
                background: #fff;
                /* white bgcolor on hover */
            }
            #navmenu li {
                /* make the list elements a containing block for the nested lists */
                position: relative;
            }
            #navmenu ul ul {
                position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100%;
                /* to position them to the right of their containing block */
                width: 100%;
                /* width is based on the containing block */
                }  
            #navmenu li {
                /* make the list elements a containing block for the nested lists */
                position: relative;
            }
            #navmenu ul ul {
                display: none;
            }
            #navmenu ul li:hover ul {
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Blog 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Blog 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Websites</a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Websites 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Websites 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Photos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9bHkj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to revisit how you are constructing the menu. For instance:

```
            <li>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

is supposed to be a `Blog` menu with two sub menus `Blog 1` and `Blog 2`. But then `<ul>` for the sub menu is supposed to be *within* the `<li>` of the menu and not separately:

```
   <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <!-- The <li> does not end here -->
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Blog 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Blog 2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>  <!-- end tag for the blog <li>, now enclosing the submenu also -->
```

Once you do this, for the other submenus as well, you have the  flying sub menus. You can now work out the location, colors etc.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote this twice:

```
#navmenu li {
    /* make the list elements a containing block for the nested lists */
    position: relative;
}
```

Your nested lists `ul` are not contained by `li` elements. So this will not work either:

```
#navmenu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

nesting your `ul` in `li` elements **may** solve your problem.